# Create an array in a function in C++ without a global variable

Tags: c++, arrays

So I would like to create an array in a function with the size set by a number coming in as the parameter. Here is an example:

```
void temp_arr ( const int array_size ) {
     int temp_arr[array_size]; //ERROR array_size needs to be a constant value
    //Then do something with the temp arr
}
```

Even if the parameter is a const int, it will not work. I would like to not use a global const and not use vectors. I am just curious as I am learning C++. I would like for it to make it so that the array size is different each time the function is called. Is there a solution to this or am I to create a const variable and the array before the function is called?

Comment: `int* temp_arr = new int[array_size]; ... delete[] temp_arr;`

Comment: @songyuanyao That's not really the same since it'd be going from static allocation to dynamic allocation.

Comment: *and not use vectors. I am just curious as I am learning C++.*  -- So you think that `std::vector` isn't C++?  What is it with `vector` why so many beginners think they shouldn't or can't use it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's not that I don't think that I should use vectors, I know that they are apart of the STL and I do use them in projects. I just want to understand what to do with arrays. It's for the purpose of just learning and I am messing around to have a better understanding of the language.

Comment: Arrays are limited and just plain dumb.  Trying to flesh out more features out of them is a waste of time, IMO.

Comment: But if there was a case where you knew the size of what a container should be, wouldn't it be faster to have the array created, as opposed to using a vector. I figure a vector would be best when you don't know the size that the array would need to be.

Comment: @kingcobra1986 Use `std::array`.  Much smarter than an array as they know their own size and don't decay to pointers when passed to functions.

Comment: Your code is valid with gcc compiler. though, it's invalid with C++ language standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a template function:

```
template<std::size_t array_size>
void temp_arr()
{
    int temp_arr[ array_size ];
    // ...work with temp_arr...
}
```

You can then call the function with this syntax:

```
temp_arr<32>(); // function will work with a 32 int statically allocated array
```

**Note**

Every call with a different value of `array_size` will instantiate a new function.

Comment: What if the size came from a variable?

Comment: @Dmitri Only if it is a `constexpr`: `constexpr std::size_t sz{ 32 }; temp_arr<sz>();` will work. The point is, it has to be available at compilation.

Comment: This worked for me. I am using a const int to pass into the template.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a value in this function, the value is not a constant. Defining an array must be done with a constant value. Although you have used `const int array_size`, that only creates an integer that is constant within the function. So in a way, if you pass a variable value in the function, it takes it as a variable. Thus it produces an error. Yes, you are to create a constant and pass it during the function call.

Comment: I tired to have a const int in main and pass that into the function. And I have also tried to add a const int that is equal to array_size inside the function. Are you saying that I should create a global variable?

Comment: @kingcobra1986 You don't have to create a global variable, see my answer.

Comment: @kingcobra1986 As shown in user2296177's answer, there is no need to create a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int const size = 10;
int array[size];
```

to create an array in C++. However, you cannot use

```
void temp_arr ( const int array_size ) {
     int temp_arr[array_size];
}
```

to create an array unless the compiler supports VLAs as an extension. The standard does not support VLAs.

The `const` qualifier in an argument type merely makes the variable `const` in the function -- you can't modify its value. However, the value cannot necessarily be determined at compile time.

For example, you can call the function using:

```
int size;
std::cout << "Enter the size of the array: ";
std::cin >> size;
temp_arr(size);
```

Since the value cannot be necessarily be determined at compile time, it can't be used to create an array.

Comment: The `const` qualifier in the argument type isn't "useless"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have issue with memory let me tell you an easy way:-

```
   void temp_arr ( const int array_size )
   {
       //lets just say you want to get the values from user and range will also be decided by the user by the variable array_size

       int arr[100];   //lets just make an array of size 100 you can increase if according to your need;
       for(int i=0; i<array_size ; i++)
       {
         scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
       }
   }
```

I know this is not a perfect solution but just a easy way for beginners.

Comment: You should include some code to prevent buffer overflows when they give the size greater than 100

Answer (score 0):

You could use a std::unique_ptr:

```
void temp_arr(int array_size)
{
    auto temp_arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(array_size);
    // code using temp_arr like a C-array
}
```